# Finding the Galois group of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In most of the text books in algebra describes the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}, \rho)$ where $\rho$ is the primitive root of unity ($\rho=e^{\frac{i2\pi}{3}})$.

The splitting field is also equal to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}, i\sqrt 3)$. Can we use this generators of the splitting filed and compute the Galois group?

For Example, an automorphism  will map  $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to the roots of the minimal polynomial of $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ which is $x^3-2$ (and the roots are $2^{\frac{1}{3}}, 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\rho , 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\rho ^2$)

And an automorphism  will map  $i\sqrt 3$ to the roots of the minimal polynomial of $i\sqrt 3$ which is $x^2+3$ (and the roots are $i\sqrt 3, -i\sqrt 3$).

Hence, there will be total $6$ automorphisms.

My motivation behind choosing these generators are to avoid any relations between generators and to avoid invalid generators.

My question is to valid to choose these generators $2^{\frac{1}{3}}, i\sqrt 3$?

Comment: What to you mean by valid? It is indeed true that $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, \rho) = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, i\sqrt{3})$ since $\rho = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ so each field contains the other.

Comment: So one can find the Galois group using these generator ?

Comment: It is often easier to find the Galois group using one set of generators rather than another, but I'll second Tob Ernack's question: What do you mean by a *valid* set of generators? My guess is that you want generators with the property that you can choose a conjugate for each generator *independently from each other*, and still there exists an automorphism realizing your choices. Is that right? In general you can't normally do it that way. I think you first have to figure out the number of automorphisms, here six.

Comment: (cont'd) Then, if it happens that you find a set of generators such that the number of combinations of their conjugates is equal to the order of the Galois group, then you can conclude. I don't think you can normally revert this process and by staring at a set of generators somehow decide that it works this way for this set but not for the other. That is, **unless** you know the extension degree also (when it is easy).

Comment: If we picked a primitive element of the extension, I think we could simply send it to each of the roots of its minimal polynomial. But that's probably what you meant by "unless you know the extension degree".